# What's the canonical transliteration of "Give me chocolate" into katakana?

Tags: loanwords

What's the canonical transliteration of "Give me chocolate" into katakana? Not as in the Babymetal song [Gimme Chocolate!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimme_Chocolate!!), but in the phrase that's described as being used by Japanese kids during occupation-era Japan (though the latter may have influenced the former). Is it ギブミーチョコレート?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is exactly as you say: 「ギブミーチョコレート」.

[image]
<sub>(source: [storage-yahoo.jp](https://blog-001.west.edge.storage-yahoo.jp/res/blog-89-cb/norioetochance/folder/13879/12/35382512/img_0_m?1423868389))</sub>